# Incorporating Inverse Probability Weights in phylogenetic imputation

Tags: machine-learning, bias-correction, selection-bias, phylogeny

In [Cortes et al. “Sample Selection Bias Correction Theory.” In Algorithmic Learning Theory, 5254:38–53. Lecture Notes in Computer Science. 2008.](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-87987-9_8), they describe how inverse probability weights can be used to correct for sampling biases when training machine learning models.

In feature/trait based machine learning models this can be done simply by including the weights as sample weights when training (e.g. many classifiers in sci-kit learn have this functionality).

I am trying to use phylogenetic imputation methods to predict a binary trait for species in a phylogeny, using methods like [corHMM](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/corHMM/versions/2.8/topics/corHMM) or [phyEstimateDisc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/picante/versions/1.8.2/topics/phyEstimate), in the presence of sampling bias i.e. the value of the binary trait is more likely to be known for certain types of species than for others and so the available training data is biased. I wonder if (1) this kind of bias will have an effect on the imputation and, if so, (2) is there a way to correct for this bias, e.g. by including inverse probability weights?